# Running a cmd command in c program file

Tags: c

here goes the problem:

suppose if I want to run a plot.exe in cmd, I wrote the following line in cmd,

> > plot image.jpg

BTW I was trying in this way in my c file:

> > system("start plot image.jpg")

the above command start the cmd and also the plot command but the image file did not popup. There is an error command:

> > "image.jpg is not def"

What does it meant by? please help me out.

Comment: The arguments to the `system()` function should be exactly as you would type them on the command line. Try calling it without "start"

Comment: still the same error msg came out dude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the process's [working directory](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_268.html) is not the directory that contains the image. You can either specify the full path to the image:

```
system("plot /full/path/to/image.jpg");
```

or use `chdir` to change the working directory before running the command:

```
if(chdir("/full/path/to/") == -1)
    ; // TODO handle error
system("plot image.jpg");
```